# Trimming MOV clips / Saving as mp4

Tags: file-formats

I am trimming extraneous time from some MOV files using the Microsoft Movies Anywhere app on my desktop. They're saved as MP4 files and have proportionately much smaller file sizes than the trimmed length would suggest (e.g. 18 sec, 228 MB MOV file / trimmed to 10 sec, 50 MB MP4 file). The content is relatively static so that wouldn't explain the difference. My principal concern: Am I losing quality by doing this? Would I be better off trimming in Resolve and saving in the same MOV format? Thanks.
Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My two cents...Video quality can be determined by several things (e.g. codec, bitrate, compression, etc.), so just looking at the container (i.e. MOV vs. MP4) isn't a sufficiently in-depth way of finding out the best option.

Comment: In addition to that,i'd like to add that you best keep high bitrate stuff while you edit and only output low bitrate (small filesize) for the final result or for archiving.